# I require assistance for converting pseudo code to Java (State machine examples)

Tags: java, state

Hello i am writing this because i have tried to convert the pseudo code below into java formatting fir around 2 days. The code i was trying to convert came from this amazing article:

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-build-a-jrpg-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6676

The code is

```
class StateMachine

Map<String, IState> mStates = new Map<String, IState>();
IState mCurrentState = EmptyState;

public void Update(float elapsedTime)
{
    mCurrentState.Update(elapsedTime);
}

public void Render()
{
    mCurrentState.Render();
}

public void Change(String stateName, optional var params)
{
    mCurrentState.OnExit();
    mCurrentState = mStates[stateName];
    mCurrentState.OnEnter(params);
}

public void Add(String name, IState state)
{
    mStates[name] = state;
}
```

and this code

```
public class StateStack

Map<String, IState> mStates = new Map<String, IState>();
List<IState> mStack = List<IState>();

public void Update(float elapsedTime)
{
    IState top = mStack.Top()
    top.Update(elapsedTime)
}

public void Render()
{
    IState top = mStack.Top()
    top.Render()
}

public void Push(String name)
{
    IState state = mStates[name];
    mStack.Push(state);
}

public IState Pop()
{
    return mStack.Pop();
}
```

i wouldn't mind if someone gives me the end result or if people guide me in the right direction. i would just like to solve this XD

*extra bit*

```
  StateMachine gGameMode = new StateMachine();

// A state for each game mode
gGameMode.Add("mainmenu",   new MainMenuState(gGameMode));
gGameMode.Add("localmap",   new LocalMapState(gGameMode));
gGameMode.Add("worldmap",   new WorldMapState(gGameMode));
gGameMode.Add("battle",     new BattleState(gGameMode));
gGameMode.Add("ingamemenu", new InGameMenuState(gGameMode));

gGameMode.Change("mainmenu");

// Main Game Update Loop
public void Update()
{
    float elapsedTime = GetElapsedFrameTime();
    gGameMode.Update(elapsedTime);
    gGameMode.Render();
}
```

*end of extra bit*

if you could guide me with this it would help me as well :P

-again thank you

Comment: So, what is the problem with the code? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: Are these examples your code, or copied from the article? If not yours, you should include as much of that as is relevant to reproduce the problem; it will help us tremendously, as we try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically Java, you just need to put the code in proper .java files and write the constructors.

etc.

```js
public class StateMachine(){
  public StateMachine(){
        
  }
}
```

The problem is you don t have code for any of the MainMenuState ... classes

Comment: i have released that this question is complete and utter garbage because of you XD

Comment: One more question, what do they mean by (optional var params)?

Comment: optional var params means you could pass some extra values to the method based on your functionality. `public void Change(String stateName, optional var params)` Could be `public void Change(String stateName, Int HealthPoints)`